# Tweepy Traceback - TypeError: on_connection_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'status_code'

Tags: tweepy

I have a discord bot that utilizes Tweepy (4.8) to post in my channel when a specific twitter account creates a new Tweet. It's worked before, and lately it hasn't. Any thoughts or help here? This is my code:

```
async def twitter():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    consumer_key = os.getenv('consumer_key')
    consumer_secret = os.getenv('consumer_secret')
    access_token = os.getenv('access_token')
    access_secret = os.getenv('access_secret')
    class StreamCollector(tweepy.asynchronous.AsyncStream):

        async def on_status(self, data):
            tweet = json.dumps(data._json)
            tweet = json.loads(tweet)
            
            if tweet['text'][0:4] == '[PC]':
                print(tweet)
                await channel.send('https://twitter.com/PUBG_Support/status/'+tweet['id_str'])
            else:
                pass

        async def on_connection_error(self, status_code):
            if status_code == 420:
            #returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
                return False
            elif status_code == 406:
                return False

                
    stream = StreamCollector(
    consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret
        )
    channel = bot.get_channel(#CHANNELCODE) #CRKR general channel
    stream.filter(follow=[882248998547070981]) #this is pubg support ID
```

And the full Error:

```
Stream encountered an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ryandiscordboyzbot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/asynchronous/streaming.py", line 109, in _connect
    async for line in resp.content:
  File "/home/ryandiscordboyzbot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 39, in __anext__
    rv = await self.read_func()
  File "/home/ryandiscordboyzbot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 338, in readline
    await self._wait("readline")
  File "/home/ryandiscordboyzbot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 306, in _wait
    await waiter
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientPayloadError: Response payload is not completed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ryandiscordboyzbot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/asynchronous/streaming.py", line 134, in _connect
    await self.on_connection_error()
TypeError: on_connection_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'status_code'
```

Comment: any thoughts here?

Comment: still troubleshooting this, any help here?

Comment: sorry any help here?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the function with the parameter `status_code`, however tweepy does not support this parameter for that function. If you would leave this out it should work fine.

The documentation about the function can be found here: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/asyncstreamingclient.html#tweepy.asynchronous.AsyncStreamingClient.on_connection_error. Where it also shows that there is no parameter for `on_connection_error`.